# Question about multiple docker-compose files in CVAT source code

Tags: docker-compose, development-environment, cvat

I've been exploring the CVAT source code and noticed the presence of multiple docker-compose files. I'm specifically interested in docker-compose.dev.yml, but it's not mentioned in the official documentation for setting up the development environment. Can someone clarify the purpose and usage of docker-compose.dev.yml in CVAT development? I'm curious if there are any additional steps or configurations I need to be aware of when using it.

I'm looking for insights into how docker-compose.dev.yml is intended to be used in the CVAT development process and if there are any specific instructions or considerations I should keep in mind.